# "npm install -g cordova" caused blue-screen-crash on Windows7

Tags: node.js, cordova

Help!! I tried to install cordova from command line, but the system was crashed with blue screen. Details below:

(1) I installed NodeJS successfully. I ran C:>npm install -g cordova from command line (cmd.exe). It started to download the files, after about 10 seconds, the computer crashed with blue screen with error of "BAD_POOL_HEADER".

(2) My computer has Windows 7 Ultimate installed. 64-bit, 4G memory, Intel Core i3-3240.

(3) I tried other 5 computers in my team. I got 3 computers crashed, and 2 computers installed successfully. I didn't see any difference among these computers. I also executed chkdsk and ensured no hard disk error.

(4) Possible root cause analysis: I copied the npm folder from a computer which had cordova installed successfully, and pasted the folder in my computer under the path of "C:\Users\kevin.kong\AppData\Roaming\npm". I got a system error saying some files can't be pasted because their file path exceeds the limitation of 260. Would it be the root cause of the blue screen crash when I installed it via npm?

an example of the too-long-path: "C:\Users\kevin.kong\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\phonegap-build\node_modules\phonegap-build-api\node_modules\request\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modules\delayed-stream\test\integration\test-delayed-stream-auto-pause.js"

Answer (score 0):

Try to map `C:\Users\kevin.kong\AppData\Roaming\npm` to a new virtual drive, it may work.

https://superuser.com/questions/644684/mapping-drive-letters-to-local-folders