# nodejs bluescreen on install

Tags: node.js, failed-installation, blue-screen-of-death

I was about to install node.js on a brand new Windows 7 64bit system. But during the installation I get a bluescreen. It happens while "copying new files". I tried node.js 8.9.4 and 9.5.0, both in 64 bit. Any idea what's wrong?
[image: bluescreen]

**edit**: I now enabled virtual memory and the message has changed. Now I get

> The driver is attempting to access memory beyond the end of the allocation.

And here the current screenshot of the dump:
[image]

Honestly, these problems seem absolutely weird... I have never before had such issues with the installation of nodejs. And I'm doing it on a new machine which is up-to-date.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439070/npm-install-g-cordova-caused-blue-screen-crash-on-windows7 of any use?

Comment: no, not really. The first time I'm having such issues with installing nodejs... somewhat strange... I still have no idea why the bluescreens appears.

Comment: I've just tried to install via commandline with Chocolatey:https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#windows but it failed too. Bluescreen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out what the issue was. It had to do with Comodo Programs Manager. After having deinstalled the program, everything worked fine again. But on my old machine I used to run Comodo Programs Manager as well. So it remains strange why it now caused such issues.